# Why response Structure Change from : to =

Tags: ios, json, swift, request, alamofire

Service Call using `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.2'` that is maximum for `Xcode 10.1` is supported, due to hardware comparability

```
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) Mac High Sierra
```

Below is Request function for login Services Call.

```
func loginRequest (urlString: String){

    let parameters = [
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "password": "YourPassword"
    ]

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                print("\n\n Success value and JSON: \(JSON)")

            case .failure(let error):
                print("\n\n Request failed with error: \(error)")

            }
        }
}
```

Response Data

```
{
    data =     {
        stauts =         {
            fullname = "yourname";
            email = "example@example.com";
            gender = "";
            notificationCount = 2;
           token = "SomeTokenString";

        };

}
```

Expected the response data in JSON Formate. But its was not.

No idea why the response structure changed from `:` to `=`

Comment: That's how are printed `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the `responseJSON` parameter the data is returned deserialized, in your case as a `[String:Any]` dictionary.

To get the raw data replace `responseJSON` with `responseData`

Comment: Your are correct! looks like its responseString  working!   Its any impact on wrapping the response String value  into codables. Sorry I have extended the question here.

Comment: For `Codable` you need the raw data